# Order created time difference

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found that code [here](https://samuelsilva.pt/cancel-woocommerce-not-paid-orders-automatically/) and I'm wondering how can I add example: `if order created time > order created time + 5 minutes`?

Now code just check today datetime and order created datetime and make datediff, but I want to make time diff.

If someone can help me, thanks already!

```
function myplugin_cancel_unpaid_wc_orders() {
    global $myplugin_options;

$my_cancel_time = $myplugin_options['myplugin_cancel_time'];

//$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( '-' . absint( $myplugin_cancel_time ) . ' MINUTES', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );

 $query = ( array(
                 'limit'   => 5,
                 'orderby' => 'date',
                 'order'   => 'DESC',
                 'status'  => array( 'pending' )
                ) );

 $orders = wc_get_orders( $query );

 foreach ( $orders as $order ) {        

     $date     = new DateTime( $order->get_date_created() );
     $today    = new DateTime();
     $interval = $date->diff($today);

     $datediff = $interval->format('%a');

     if ( $datediff >= 4 ) {
         $order->update_status('cancelled', 'Cancelled for missing payment');
     }  
  }
}
```

Comment: "if order created time > order created time + 5 minutes" makes no sense. How can the order created time be greater than that same value increased? Perhaps you meant "if now > order created time + 5 minutes"?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the order created date to seconds. 5 minutes equal 300 seconds.

```
$order_created_date = $order->get_date_created(); // Get order date created WC_DateTime Object

$order_created_seconds = $order_created_date->getTimestamp(); // Get order create date in seconds

$end_time = $order_created_seconds+300; // Order created time + 5mins
$current_time = time();

if ($current_time >= $end_time) { // Check if end time
    $order->update_status('cancelled', 'Cancelled for missing payment');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test your code. I found typo in here:
$order_cerated_date->getTimestamp();